# AddHttpClient in Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, mvvm-toolkit

I am refractoring an .NET C# application to the latest MS MVVM Toolkit. MS suggests the `refit` as a goto library to interact with REST API. However, I would like to use `AddHttpClient` following Ioc (Inversion of control) pattern. Below is the sample code I would like to refractor however it throws an error:

```cs
Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(
    new ServiceCollection()
    //Services
    .AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>()
    // Change below line to AddHttpClient
    .AddSingleton(RestService.For<IRedditService>("https://www.reddit.com/"))
    //ViewModels
    .AddTransient<PostWidgetViewModel>()
    //I would like to do below but it throws error
    .AddHttpClient<IRedditService>()
    .BuildServiceProvider());
```

So the question is how to register `AddHttpClient` in `Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices`?

Error

> 'IHttpClientBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'BuildServiceProvider' and the best extension method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First populate the collection

```cs
var collection = new ServiceCollection();
collection.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
collection.AddSingleton(RestService.For<IRedditService>("https://www.reddit.com/"));
collection.AddTransient<PostWidgetViewModel>();
collection.AddHttpClient<IRedditService>();
```

then you should call the `BuildServiceProvider` method on the `ServiceCollection`

```cs
Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(collection.BuildServiceProvider());
```

Comment: I have tried this already (see above) ... but I am getting the stated error.

Comment: @Jim You can't get the same error, since my suggested solution calls the `BuildServiceProvider` method on the `IServiceCollection` against which this method is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectioncontainerbuilderextensions.buildserviceprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Comment: @Jim Since the `AddHttpClient` returns an `IHttpClientBuilder` implementation to be able to call methods like `AddPolicyHandler` that's why you can't call the `BuildServiceProvider` on that.

Comment: I guess the question remains .... how to properly register AddHttpClient

Comment: @Jim what do you mean by *properly*?

Comment: I mean that the suggested answer/snippet does not work. Therefore I my question in the original post remains i.e. how to register AddHttpClient in Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices if that possible at all .. if not then what are the alternatives

Comment: @Jim Could you please elaborate what  do you mean by not working? Compile time error? Runtime error? Or what? Could you please be a more specific?

Comment: the error description is stated in the question:
'IHttpClientBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'BuildServiceProvider' and the best extension method

Comment: @Jim With my proposed solution you can not receive this error. In my solution the BuildServiceProvider method call is not chained after the AddHttpClient rather it is called directly on the collection variable.

Comment: it did actually worked.... it had to be written exactly as Ioc.Default.ConfigureServices(collection.BuildServiceProvider());
 no other way which is really really weird.